# use slash "/" instead of query string symbol "?"

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, query-string

I have an ASP.NET (webforms) project, and there is an aspx page named "Category(.aspx)". in this page, I get a query string named "categoryId" which is the category primary key in the database, and you probably know the continuation.

So, in that way, the URL would be something like this: "MySite.com/Category.aspx?cid=1" which I don't think is really pretty!
Is there a way to change the question symbol (?) (to slash "/") and query string name to have a prettier URL like: MySite.com/Category.aspx/10
(for example something like routing in ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to register route in your application start. For reference 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx